# How do I find an element with a certain class in a web page with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have tried to find a table with class "data" in a web page with this code.

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.cbssports.com/nba/draft/mock-draft').read())

rows = soup.findAll("table.data")
print rows
```

However, I am getting none for rows even though I am sure that a table with class "data" exists on that page. What is the proper way to find an element with class "data" on a web page with BeautifulSoup?

Comment: So are you trying to parse out their picks for the mock draft?  Or do something else entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pick up the rows, you'll need the following

```
import urllib2
from BeautifuSoup import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.cbssports.com/nba/draft/mock-draft').read())

# if there's only one table with class = data
table = soup.find('table', attrs = {'class' : 'data'})

# if there are multiple tables with class = data
table = soup.findAll('table', attrs = {'class' : 'data'})[n]
# suppose you need the n-th table of the list returned

rows = table.findAll('tr') # gives all the rows, you can set attrs to filter
```

Then you can also iterate through the columns:

```
for row in rows:
    cols = row.findAll('td')
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You want something like

```
rows = soup.find_all('table', attrs = {"class": "data"})
```

instead of your current line (tested). The class of an element is an attribute, so you filter by attribute in `find_all`. This line returns a large table element from your sample page.

Comment: I don't know what to say - that code works on my computer. The only difference is that I'm using "from bs4 import BeautifulSoup" instead of the import line in the question. Apart from that, the `rows` variable has the table element when I run my script.

Comment: this is the error it pops TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: For which line? Maybe your urlopen call is failing?